# Form submission redirect instead of echoing success message?

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect

I am currently using a PHP form processor to send an email with form fields. I would like to convert this processor so that upon sucessful submission it will redirect you to a different page instead of echoing a success message(like it does currently). Below is the code I am using for the processor. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "your@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Email Subject Goes Here";


    $organization_name_field = $_POST['organization'];  //required
    $contact_name_field = $_POST['name'];       //required
    $city_field = $_POST['city'];           //not required
    $state_field = $_POST['state'];           //not required
    $zipcode_field = $_POST['zip'];           //not required
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];           //not required
    $phone_number_field = $_POST['phone'];        //not required
    $email_message = "Form details below:\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Organization Name: ".clean_string($organization_name_field)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact Name: ".clean_string($contact_name_field)."\n";
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city_field)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state_field)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Zip Code: ".clean_string($zipcode_field)."\n";   
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_field)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($phone_number_field)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$contact_name_field."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_field."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: just add `header('Location: someotherpage.php');` instead of the thank you ...

Comment: Never use those error-suppressing `@`s! Please check the status of the `mail` function to see if the message was correctly sent (to the SMTP server).

Comment: The email comes through correctly, I just can't get the form to redirect to the thank you page.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the following:

```
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

With:

```
//Redirect user to another page
header('Location: email-success.php'); //Replace email-success.php with the page you want them to be redirected to!
}
?>
```